# inheritance working on simulator but not on Iphone!

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, inheritance, xcode4

I have come across a weird error...
I have a class that extends another, getting some variables from it. Its a really simple one.
when i compile the code for the simulator, it works great. When I run in the Iphone, it get an error that states that the vairable is not set!. The code:
parent class header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TarefaMap.h"


@interface GenericTarefaTableView : UITableViewController {
TarefaMap* tarefaMap;
TarefaMap* tarefaMapOriginal;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) TarefaMap* tarefaMap;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TarefaMap* tarefaMapOriginal;


@end
```

parent class implementation:

```
#import "GenericTarefaTableView.h"


@implementation GenericTarefaTableView
@synthesize tarefaMap,tarefaMapOriginal;


@end
```

child class header:

```
@interface EditTarefaViewController : GenericTarefaTableView <UITextFieldDelegate , UITextViewDelegate> {

Tarefa* tarefa;
NSArray *fieldLabels;
UITextField *textFieldBeginEdited;
BOOL isEdit;
IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell0;
IBOutlet UITextView* textView;
NSManagedObjectContext* context;



}

@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSManagedObjectContext* context;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView* textView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell0;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Tarefa* tarefa;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField* firstField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *fieldLabels;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textFieldBeingEdited;

@end
```

Child class implementation:

```
#import "EditTarefaViewController.h"

@implementation EditTarefaViewController



@synthesize tarefa, textFieldBeingEdited,firstField,fieldLabels,textView, cell0, context;
NSMutableArray *textFieldarray;
UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
UITableViewCell* cell1;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{


NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad");
[super viewDidLoad];
self.tarefaMap=[[TarefaMap alloc] initWithTarefa:tarefa];
self.tarefaMapOriginal=[[TarefaMap alloc] initWithTarefa:tarefa];

if ([tarefaMapOriginal isEqual:tarefaMap]) {
    NSLog(@"SOMOS IGUAIS!!!!!");
}
   NSLog(@"Comparando tarefas!!!!!");
if ([tarefaMapOriginal isEqualtoTarefaMap:tarefaMap]) {
    NSLog(@"SOMOS IGUAIS2!!!!!");
}
}
```

This compiles fine on the simulator, but when i Try on the IPhone, I get an error saying that the variables tarefaMap is undeclared, and should be declared on the function...

any thoughts?

Comment: Try `[self.tarefaMapOriginal isEqual:self.tarefaMap]`, also, post the exact error and on what line it occurs.  That helps.

Comment: The problem could stem from the variables being @protected by default in your simulator build, and @private in your iphone build.  That's just a guess though, as I have no idea how you'd do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface EditTarefaViewController : GenericTarefaTableView <UITextFieldDelegate , UITextViewDelegate> {
```

before that line add this

```
@class GenericTarefaTableView;
```

then in .m file add

```
import "GenericTarefaTableView.h"
```

and change like in viewdidload

```
NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad");
[super viewDidLoad];
super.tarefaMap=[[TarefaMap alloc] initWithTarefa:tarefa];
super.tarefaMapOriginal=[[TarefaMap alloc] initWithTarefa:tarefa];


@implementation EditTarefaViewController
```

before that u have to import TarefaMap.h and also declare this in EditTarefaViewController.h file with like this

```
@class TarefaMap;
```